# ( Python basico ) Explicación del siguiente codigo en Python porfavor

Tags: python

estoy aprendiendo Python de un libro, y justo en esta parte no explica nada. Me gustaria pedir que alguien me explicase un poco o me remities a algun lugar donde se explican las bases de programación orientada a objetos en Python.

```
class Punto:
    def __init__ (self, x, y):
        self.X = x
        self.Y = y
    def MostrarPunto(self):
        print("El punto es (",self.X,",",self.Y,")")
p1 = Punto(4,6)
p1.MostrarPunto()
```

Segun lo que entiendo
class Punto: definimos clase
def **init** (self, x, y): inicializamos, pero no veo caundo llamamos a esta función, ni porque tiene 3 variables (self, x, y) en vez de dos si son coordenadas de un punto.

self.X = x no entiendo que uso tiene el punto

p1.MostrarPunto() de igual modo no entiendo el uso del punto.

Gracias por cualquier ayuda. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

El método `__init__` es invocado cuando creas un objeto:

```
p1 = Punto(4,6) # Invoca el método __init__()
```

En los métodos de una clase, el primer argumento es siempre el objeto al cual se aplica el método. No lo tienes que pasar, por el simple hecho de escribir

```
p1.MostrarPunto()
```

estás diciendo que `self` es `p1`. La llamada que se ejecuta "por debajo" es

```
MostrarPunto(p1)
```

Answer (score 1):

El método `__init__()` de una clase, significa que es su *constructor*. Esto significa que cuando tú instancias la clase, es decir, cuando creas el objeto en esta línea: `p1 = Punto(4,6)` (el objeto es p1), **automáticamente** se invoca al método constructor.

¿Qué es self?
Self hace referencia a la propia instancia, es decir, al propio objeto instanciado. Piensa que cuando tenemos el objeto creado, p1, dentro de la clase sería "self". Todos los métodos de una clase tienen que llevar el objeto self. Cuando el constructor se ejecuta, lo que dice es: "ok, acabo de recibir una solicitud de instancia de este objeto, con dos parámetros *4* y *6*, que corresponden a *x* e *y*. Vale, pues me voy a guardar estos valores en dos atributos de la clase *self.x* y *self.y*." Es decir, cuando tú creas el objeto, estás diciendo que quieres que el punto tenga esos dos valores. La instancia recoge esos valores y los almacena en el objeto. Por lo tanto, siempre que dentro de la clase quieras usar *x* e *y*, deberás usar *self.x* y *self.y*.

Si pruebas a poner al final de tu código `print(p1.x)`, verás que te imprimirá por pantalla el valor de x.

A la hora de invocar el resto de métodos, solo hay que usar el nombre del objeto, punto y el nombre del método.

Para más información, es muy interesante que leas esto de la documentación oficial: [Clases en Python](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/classes.html)

Answer (score 1):

Todos los métodos de una clase en python deben declarar un primer parámetro (que típicamente se llama `self`, pero el nombre no es palabra especial en el lenguaje).

Cuando invocas un método sobre un objeto mediante la sintaxis `objeto.metodo(parametros)`, en realidad Python invoca ese mismo método sobre la clase, y le pasa el objeto como primer parámetro. Por ejemplo si la clase del objeto es `ClaseA`, entonces `objeto.metodo(parametros)` se convierte en `ClaseA.metodo(objeto, parametros)`.

De ese modo, una vez estás dentro del método, el primer parámetro contiene el objeto sobre el que quieres actuar. A ese primer parámetro, como dije, se le suele llamar `self`, pero nada te impide darle cualquier otro nombre que se te ocurra (no lo recomiendo, pues otros pythonistas podrían verse confundidos al ver tu código).

El constructor es un caso especial. Es un método como cualquier otro, pero la forma de invocarlo es diferente. Se invoca cuando llamas a la clase como si fuera una función. En particular cuando haces:

```
p1 = Punto(4, 6)
```

lo que ocurre "tras el telón" es algo así como lo siguiente:

```
objeto_auxiliar = Punto.__new__()       # Se crea una instancia de ese tipo
Punto.__init__(objeto_auxiliar, 4, 6)   # Se llama al constructor
p1 = objeto_auxiliar                    # Finalmente se asigna el resultado
```

Dentro de `__init__()` el parámetro `self` tiene el mismo significado que dentro de cualquier otro método de esa clase: representa el objeto sobre el que se está actuando.

Así cuando haces `self.X = x` en el ejemplo anterior, estás asignando el campo `X` del objeto auxiliar, que en última instancia será `p1.X`. Pero si después haces `p2 = Punto(10, 20)`, entonces estarías asignando el de otro objeto auxiliar que al final sería `p2.X`. De este modo cada instancia (`p1`, `p2`) tiene sus propios valores en los atributos.

Cuando después hagas `p1.MostrarPunto()` eso se convertirá en `Punto.MostrarPunto(p1)` por lo que el parámetro `self` que recibes se refiere al objeto `p1` y cuando desde dentro imprimes `self.X`, estás imprimiendo `p1.X`, pero si hubieras hecho`p2.MostrarPunto()` estarías imprimiendo `p2.X`.